# dataframe replace() is not working inside function

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I was replacing some strings (removing whitespaces) inside multiple dataframes manually, then I decided to centralize this code inside a function as follows (the print statements are just for debugging):

```
def merge_multiword_teams(dfnx,team_lst):
    print(dfnx[dfnx['team'].str.contains('lazer')])
    for s in team_lst:
        c=s.replace(' ','')
        print(s + c)
        dfnx.replace({s,c},inplace=True)
        print(dfnx[dfnx['team'].str.contains('lazer')])
    return dfnx
```

then calling it

```
df = merge_multiword_teams(df,['Trail Blazers'])
```

the print statement shows that the whitespaces were not replaced

team   W   L   W/L%    GB   PS/G   PA/G    SRS  year  
17   Portland Trail Blazers  49  33  0.598  16.0  105.6  103.0    2.6  2018
52   Portland Trail Blazers  41  41    0.5  26.0  107.9  108.5  -0.23  2017
79   Portland Trail Blazers  44  38  0.537  29.0  105.1  104.3   0.98  2016
109  Portland Trail Blazers  51  31   .622        102.8   98.6   4.41  2015
146  Portland Trail Blazers  54  28   .659   5.0  106.7  102.8   4.44  2014

Trail BlazersTrailBlazers
team   W   L   W/L%    GB   PS/G   PA/G    SRS  year  
17   Portland Trail Blazers  49  33  0.598  16.0  105.6  103.0    2.6  2018
52   Portland Trail Blazers  41  41    0.5  26.0  107.9  108.5  -0.23  2017
79   Portland Trail Blazers  44  38  0.537  29.0  105.1  104.3   0.98  2016
109  Portland Trail Blazers  51  31   .622        102.8   98.6   4.41  2015
146  Portland Trail Blazers  54  28   .659   5.0  106.7  102.8   4.44  2014

what can be wrong with this approach ? given that moving the replace statement outside the function works perfectly

Comment: I think the problem is that you've put `s` and `c` as a set when I think you meant it as a dict (`{s:c}`)?

Comment: correct, thank u .. u can put it as answer so that I accept it

Comment: Sure, I've added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've put `s` and `c` as a set when I think you meant it as a dict (`{s:c}`)